# (Linux CLI PHP) Capturing CURL's verbose output to file during execution

Tags: php, linux, curl, command-line

I just noticed that if you run a command line php script that utilizes curl with the CURLOPT_VERBOSE option on, you can't capture the output...

Example:

```
$php myscript.php > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

All of the PHP output will go into the logfile, but curl's output still hits the screen.

How can I capture both PHP output with the curl output?

```
    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agentString);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Edit:

Adding the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, STDOUT);
```

Seems to do the trick. However, now it seems that the curl output conflicts with php's output and overwrites the log file with its own output. Weird!

Edit 2:

This works

```
 $php myscript.php >> logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: output buffer like Haig Bedrosian suggested, but instead of `ob_end_flush()` use `ob_end_clear()` instead

Comment: ob doesn't work, which is the issue. We can't modify the curl options without modifying the 3rd party client, so we're looking for a flexible way to hide this spammy info when verbose/debug isn't needed. The client doesn't permit changing its default options.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my first answer is wrong. cURL's manual page says:

> URLOPT_VERBOSE    TRUE to output verbose information. Writes output to
>   STDERR, or the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR.

So specifying `STDOUT` for `CURLOPT_STDERR` will work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, STDOUT);
```

**Original answer**:

Check that you're also setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.

Comment: @GabrielAlack Yeah sorry, I fixed my answer with the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should do an actual answer instead of just a comment.
I just realized you WANT all the content.

```
ob_start()

$ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agentString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

// What ever other functions you want run...

// discard content: ob_end_clean()
$extra_curl_stuff = ob_get_flush();
// save $extra_curl_stuff to your logfile too...
```

Comment: The function is ob_end_clean not clear. And this doesn't work. :(

Comment: You are right. It is clean. Haha. This is what happens when I get tired. Changed it. But I changed it to be with `ob_get_flush()` instead. =P

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a PHP solution, you can use CURL options:

```
...
// this returns the data instead of outputing it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// output the data
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Or you can buffer and flush the output:

```
// turn on output buffering
ob_start();

// do some curl operations here

// flush and turn off buffering
ob_end_flush();
```